# Microsoft Visual Studio Intellisense not picking selected variable?

Tags: c++, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

So, my problem is quite simple and likely just dumb.
So, I'm coding in C++ using Visual Studio Community 2017 and intellisense is working normally and showing an accurate list of what I might be thinking about and highlighting one of the choices. The problem is that I can't press any key to actually choose that option! Enter just breaks line, tab tabs and space adds a space and none finish the word I'm typing. Is this working as intended? And if so is there a way to change it? It's really affecting my workflow.

I should mention that double clicking on the option does work. It's just that I can't find any sensible shortcut for the effect.

Comment: same problem for me, it is driving me crazy

Answer (score -1):

If you use the arrow keys to move to a lower option, then enter should work to insert the value. The first time you arrow down I don't think it will actually move the to a lower one, but it will allow you to click enter.

+---------+
|**varOne** |
+---------+
|varTwo |
+---------+
Arrow Down
+---------+
|**varOne** |
+---------+
|varTwo |
+---------+
(same value highlited and you can click enter)

Comment: hitting enter is just adding a new line in VS2017